# How can I show the child categories (links) in the sidebar under the parent categories using Enfold Theme WordPress

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

[image]

Live test site: https://www.epoxytec.com/projects-profiles-test/

Is there a function code that can make this possible?

I tried this code but it doesnt work how I want it to.

`if(!function_exists('avia_custom_query_extension'))
{
function avia_custom_query_extension($query, $params)
{
global $avia_config;
if(!empty($avia_config['avia_custom_query_options']['order']))
{
$query['order'] = $avia_config['avia_custom_query_options']['order'];
}

```
    if(!empty($avia_config['avia_custom_query_options']['orderby']))
    {
        $query['orderby'] = $avia_config['avia_custom_query_options']['orderby'];
    }

    unset($avia_config['avia_custom_query_options']);

    return $query;
}

add_filter('avia_masonry_entries_query', 'avia_custom_query_extension', 10, 2);
add_filter('avia_post_grid_query', 'avia_custom_query_extension', 10, 2);
add_filter('avia_post_slide_query', 'avia_custom_query_extension', 10, 2);
add_filter('avia_blog_post_query', 'avia_custom_query_extension', 10, 2);
add_filter('avf_magazine_entries_query', 'avia_custom_query_extension', 10, 2);

add_filter('avf_template_builder_shortcode_elements','avia_custom_query_options', 10, 1);
function avia_custom_query_options($elements)
{
    $allowed_elements = array('av_blog','av_masonry_entries','av_postslider','av_portfolio','av_magazine');

    if(isset($_POST['params']['allowed']) && in_array($_POST['params']['allowed'], $allowed_elements))
    {
        $elements[] = array(
            "name" => __("Custom Query Orderby",'avia_framework' ),
            "desc" => __("Set a custom query orderby value",'avia_framework' ),
            "id"   => "orderby",
            "type"  => "select",
            "std"   => "",
            "subtype" => array(
                __('Default Order',  'avia_framework' ) =>'',
                __('Title',  'avia_framework' ) =>'title',
                __('Random',  'avia_framework' ) =>'rand',
                __('Date',  'avia_framework' ) =>'date',
                __('Author',  'avia_framework' ) =>'author',
                __('Name (Post Slug)',  'avia_framework' ) =>'name',
                __('Modified',  'avia_framework' ) =>'modified',
                __('Comment Count',  'avia_framework' ) =>'comment_count',
                __('Page Order',  'avia_framework' ) =>'menu_order')
        );

        $elements[] = array(
            "name" => __("Custom Query Order",'avia_framework' ),
            "desc" => __("Set a custom query order",'avia_framework' ),
            "id"   => "order",
            "type"  => "select",
            "std"   => "",
            "subtype" => array(
                __('Default Order',  'avia_framework' ) =>'',
                __('Ascending Order',  'avia_framework' ) =>'ASC',
                __('Descending Order',  'avia_framework' ) =>'DESC'));
    }

    return $elements;
}

add_filter('avf_template_builder_shortcode_meta', 'avia_custom_query_add_query_params_to_config', 10, 4);
function avia_custom_query_add_query_params_to_config($meta, $atts, $content, $shortcodename)
{
    global $avia_config;
    if(empty($avia_config['avia_custom_query_options'])) $avia_config['avia_custom_query_options'] = array();

    if(!empty($atts['order']))
    {
        $avia_config['avia_custom_query_options']['order'] = $atts['order'];
    }

    if(!empty($atts['orderby']))
    {
        $avia_config['avia_custom_query_options']['orderby'] = $atts['orderby'];
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

}`